# Implementar ajax em codigo já pronto

Tags: php, html, ajax

Eu gostaria de ao invés de mandar para outra pagin. Usar ajax mas eu não sei se seria possível só alterar algumas coisas no código ou se teria que refazer o código... ?

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header amigo">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Login</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="../php/login.php" method="POST">
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login">

          </div>

          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Senha" placeholder="Senha">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastroModal">
                                    Cadastrar-se
                                </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="entrar" name="entrar">Entrar</button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    <?php
session_start([

]);

if(isset($_POST['entrar'])){
    $conexao= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","restaurante");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexao,"utf8");


    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['Senha'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Login='$login' AND Senha='$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
    $regis = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($regis > 0){
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
        echo "Entrou";
        header('Location: ../php/page2.php');
    }else{
        echo "Não entrou na conta";

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Então quando o usuário digitar as informações corretas de login e clicar em **Entrar**, o que você quer que aconteça?

Comment: Ajax e somente um "opçao" para usar XMLHttpRequest. Da uma olhada aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para passar isso para ajax será necessário as seguintes mudanças:

HTML: só coloquei id nos campos

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header amigo">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Login</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="../php/login.php" method="POST">
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id ="login" name="login" placeholder="Login">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
            </div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="Senha" placeholder="Senha">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastroModal">
                Cadastrar-se
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="entrar" id="entrar"name="entrar">Entrar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery: pega o click do botão de entrar e envia por ajax,perceba que deixei o success do ajax vazio, assim ele ira cadastrar porém não fará nada na tela, pelo o que entendi você não quer que mude a tela, porém o usuário não saberá se logou ou não.

```
$('#entrar').click(function () {
    var dados = {
        'login': $('#login').val(),
        'senha': $('#senha').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: exemplo.com,
        data: dados,
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (data) {}
    })
});
```

AJAX: fiz poucas mudanças no seu código

```
<?php
session_start([

]);

if(isset($_POST)){
    $conexao= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","restaurante");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexao,"utf8");

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['Senha'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Login='$login' AND Senha='$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
    $regis = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($regis > 0){
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['login']);
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode('Não entrou na conta');
    }
}

?>
```

Obs: caso queira implementar algo no js quando lgoar pode ser feito no success, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: cara... você simplesmente salvou minha vida kkkkk eu nunca usei ajax e pra mim está sendo um inferno, eu fiquei 5hrs quebrando a cabeça e isso dando errado pra mim, eu tenho esse modal que inseri aqui em um menu, eu gostaria de quando o cara logar aparecer o nome dele no lugar do botão que é o de login no caso, é possivel ?